# GIT not picking up changes when files are copied

Tags: git, repository, commit, changeset

This one keeps me puzzled for quiet some time now.
Situation

- Folder Scr is a git repository
- Folder Changes is a plain windows folder

Files are getting exported to Changes folder and then copied to Scr folder, it is 100% sure that each file in Changes is a new or modified file.

We checked that files being copied from Changes to Scr are really being added or modified, this is the case. New files are detected by git but modified ones not always , certainly not when they are binary. All binary files are marked as binary in the git arguments.

Anyone any ideas ? Please don't argue about the set up, I also had to accept this :-)

git update-index --really-refresh neither helped

What I'm expecting , that git detects any file modification, regardless of file type.

Comment: Can you get a file that you are _sure_ is different between `HEAD` and the working tree and run a hashsum (md5 or sha1 or 256) over the file in `HEAD` and the one in the tree? So... something like `git show HEAD:some-file | md5sum -; md5sum some-file`, show us that it is different in hashes and then the output of `git status some-file`?

Comment: @eftshift0
$ git show HEAD:Src/Bin/vb6/data/Austria.mdb | md5sum
2e3011fde15a05726fff19e33cf5b98b *-
$ git show Src/Bin/vb6/data/Austria.mdb | md5sum
cda909c763db48b54d8fd3f1f7ed8fc2 *-
$ git status  Src/Bin/vb6/data/Austria.mdb
On branch trunk
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/trunk'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Add it to the question, please.

Comment: Use `git show` only once (to get it from `HEAD`). Then the second md5sum has to be against the file itself, not through git (`git show some-file` will **not** show you the file as you have it in the working tree).

Comment: My bad sorry !
both md5sum show the same value so I kind of understand why git doesn't pick it up.
But I swear the file has changed checking the diff in subversion

Index: Austria.mdb

--- Austria.mdb (revision 2)
+++ Austria.mdb (revision 3)

Property changes on: Austria.mdb
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:needs-lock
## -0,0 +1 ##
+*
\ No newline at end of property

Comment: Feel free to add that in the question..... also whatever additional information svn can provide about said change. That doesn't look (at least to my untrained-in-svn eyes) like a content change.

Comment: Can you try to do the same thing about making svn show you the file on both revisions and check their checksums?

Comment: What version of git are you using? Are you using differing filename capitalization?